# Getting bitmap from external storage

Tags: android, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream, android-bitmap

I have saved a bitmap to external storage via FileOutputStream and am trying to retrieve that file in another class so that it can be put into a imageView. Here is where I save the bitmap:

```
public void SaveImage(Bitmap default_b) {

    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 100000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "Image-" + n +".png";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    Log.i("AppInfoAdapter", "" + file);
    if (file.exists()) file.delete();
    try {
        // File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
            //  + "/" + fname + ".png");
        // FileOutputStream out = mContext.getApplicationContext().openFileOutput("bitmapA", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        default_b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and I am trying to recieve it here:

```
  @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Try to reuse the views
    ImageView view = (ImageView) convertView;
    // if convert view is null then create a new instance else reuse it
    if (view == null) {
        view = new ImageView(Context);
        Log.d("GridViewAdapter", "new imageView added");
    }
    try {
        FileInputStream in = Context.openFileInput("bitmapA");
        BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(in);
        byte[] bitMapA = new byte[buf.available()];
        buf.read(bitMapA);
        Bitmap bM = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitMapA, 0, bitMapA.length);
        view.setImageBitmap(bM);
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
        if (buf != null) {
            buf.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    view.setImageResource(drawables.get(position));
    view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    view.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
    view.setTag(String.valueOf(position));
    return view;
}
```

I have done plenty of searching on this and have come across multiple ways of doing the same thing but for at the moment, this way of doing it doesn't work.

I have seen it where you use openFileOutput and openFileInput and then I have also seen where people just create new FileInput and Output streams.

Which one is better to use for the bitmap?

and then depending on which one is better to use (since I have both set up for when I save the bitmap), how can I get that bitmap from external storage?

Thanks!